# Ranking Priority using DropDownList in C#

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

My idea is to build a Ranking Priority using a DropDownList ASP server control.

Here's my setup: I have 3 DropDownLists and it has 3 items ("First", "Second", "Third") on each DropDownLists. When I have chosen the 1st DropDownList assuming the item I have selected is "First" and on the 2nd DropDownList by default its SelectedItem is "First" also the item of the 1st DropDownList on which I have selected must be swapped on the 2nd DropDownList.

In short there would be unique SelectedItems on each DropDownList and in every SelectedIndexChanged event occuring there would be swapping of items on the 3 DropDownLists. That's what my Ranking Priority would be.

My question would be, how can I swapped a previous item on the DropDownList going from one another DropDownList where I have selected on and placed a new item?

Here's my code:

```
protected void DropDownListPriority_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DropDownList ddlRank = (DropDownList)sender;

    int swapIndex;
    string sameDdlSelectedItemID;


        //Get list of DDLs
        List<DropDownList> ddlRankList = new List<DropDownList>();
        ddlRankList.Add(ddlBiometricNoOrder);
        ddlRankList.Add(ddlDateTimeOrder);
        ddlRankList.Add(ddlTransactionTypeOrder);

        //Store ListItems for DDL
        List<string> strRankList = new List<string>();
        strRankList.Add("First");
        strRankList.Add("Second");
        strRankList.Add("Third");

        //Holds temp. DDL
        List<DropDownList> tempRankList = new List<DropDownList>();

        //Remove the '<-- Select -->' item when ddl is changed
        if(ddlRank.Items.Contains(new ListItem("<-- Select -->")))
            ddlRank.Items.RemoveAt(0);                

        //Loop on each List<T>
        for(int x = 0; x < ddlRankList.Count; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < ddlRankList.ElementAt(x).Items.Count; y++)
            {
                if (ddlRankList.ElementAt(x).Items[y].Text != ddlRank.SelectedItem.Text)
                {
                    //Check amongst the unselected item to be changed (int swapIndex)
                    swapIndex = Convert.ToInt32(ddlRankList.ElementAt(x).Items[y].Value);
                }
            }
        }

        foreach (DropDownList ddl in ddlRankList)
        {
            foreach (string strRank in strRankList)
            {
                if (ddlRank.SelectedItem.Text == ddl.SelectedItem.Text)
                {
                    sameDdlSelectedItemID = ddl.ID;

                    //Set the ddl SelectedIndex
                    ddl.SelectedIndex = //This is my question;

                }
            }
        }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I see that you have considered an approach where the lists are repopulated at server end. Is there any specific reason for it as server postbacks could be costly. Instead why don't you consider a jquery/javascript based solution where the lists are manipulated based on user selected values.

You can implement the event based model as well. Refer [this](http://brandonaaron.net/blog/2010/03/4/event-delegation-with-jquery)